# Is it possible to make a element show but not interact-able

Tags: javascript, html, css

is it any way possible to make a element basically act as if it isn't there but still visible. I am creating a custom mouse pointer with the index higher than 0 but this interrupts, cause the element is blocking the mouse from clicking.

```js
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursorr");

const moveCursor = (e) => {
  const mouseY = e.clientY;
  const mouseX = e.clientX;

  cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0)`;

}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor)
```

```css
#cursorr {
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.8%;
  top: -1.5%;
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
}

sqr {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<cursor id="cursorr"></cursor>

<input id="sqr">

</html>
```

also I don't like how most of the custom circles on the internet are offset to the right I like them over the top of the mouse : that might be a problem not sure.

Comment: [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: can you explain more? pointer events none doesn't really help without context

Comment: You can google it. You're expected to do research before asking a question.

Comment: I have and I am unsure of what it is that this is going to do I looked at the link you sent me and have no clue on what your trying to tell me? mate I searched on the internet for 2hrs before coming here.

Comment: MDN (the link I supplied) explains it pretty thoroughly. What part don't you understand?

Comment: I am confused on where to put the code, please write an answer and explain it so other people can know to

Comment: Well, it's CSS. So I imagine it goes in with the rest of your CSS. Part of researching is gaining a basic understanding of the topic. This can sometimes take a while but is necessary.

Comment: If you mouse over the downvote button, you might see a tooltip that says, in part, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You now have more information to inform your research. Use it.

Comment: <input id="sqr" disabled>?